# stopPropagation of jquery not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I a currently working on a ui recorder where I some times absorb the events using stopPropagation of jquery which is defined as

```
    stopPropagation: function () {
        this.isPropagationStopped = K;
        var a = this.originalEvent;
        !a || (a.stopPropagation && a.stopPropagation(), a.cancelBubble = !0)
    }
```

By jquery. I eat the event as

```
    absorbClick: function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

and attach the event to all the elements by the function

```
  jQuery(frame.document).bind("click", {}, function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }, true);
```

What is surprising is that for some of the websites, I fail to absorb the click events while  for some of websites. It works properly.

Above process does not work fort this sample website. Even before the absorClick function is called the text changes in the following one. Why am I not able to absorb event?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Repro</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mydiv">Click me!</div>
        <script>
            $('#mydiv').click(function() { $('#mydiv').html("You have clicked me!") });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

while it does work for

```
<div class="central-featured-lang lang1" lang="en">
    <a class="link-box" href="//en.wikipedia.org/" title="English — Wikipedia — The Free Encyclopedia"><strong>English</strong><br>
        <em>The Free Encyclopedia</em><br>
        <small>4 479 000+ articles</small>
    </a>
</div>
```

All the above process is part of https://github.com/sebuilder/se-builder/blob/master/seleniumbuilder/chrome/content/html/js/builder/verifyexplorer.js. I am fixing this issue present for sebuilder.

Comment: What do you mean by "absorb" the event? What exactly should happen in the first example and what does happen?

Comment: In the first example text should not change. In a way when I am absorb event. Nothing should happen to that event.

Comment: The problem is that that event handler is executed before your event handler is executed, because it is directly bound to the element. Your event handler is added to the root of document, so it will be the *very last* handler that is executed for any event. If you wanted to capture events *before* any other handler is triggered, you have to bind the handler in the capture phase. See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener. jQuery doesn't let you do that for compatibility reasons.

Comment: `$().bind` is outdated. Use `$().on` in new code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the event handler in the example is executed before your event handler is executed, since it is directly bound to the element.

Your event handler is added to the root of document, so it will be the very last handler that is executed for any event.

If you want to capture events before any other handler is triggered, you have to bind the handler in the c[apture phase](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html), with [`addEventListener`:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
}, true); // <- passing true binds the handler in the capture phase
```

jQuery doesn't let you do that for compatibility reasons. IE browsers that don't support `addEventListener` also don't support binding in the capture phase.

Comment: IE9 does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Browser_compatibility, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975245%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks works like a charm when I replace bind with eventlistener. This is a firefoxc plugin I am working on, So dont need to bother about internet explorer. I disable all event listeners in verify mode and they work normal in normal modes. In the verify mode all the native event handlers are disables but can't get out of that mode. Still figuring out.